# DLL Load Failed, Not a Valid Win32 App showing for both x86 & x64 DLLs

Tags: python, dll

Trying to run the latest version of heatmap. http://jjguy.com/heatmap/

DLL load keeps crapping out on me in both 64 & 32 bit dlls. (Similar questions on this seemed irrelevant as I've tried loading both DLLs)

I'm running Windows 7. I have uninstalled and re-installed 2.7.3 64 bit.

### Idle Top line:

> Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:24:47) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

### I've tried loading

C:\Python27\DLLs\cHeatmap-x86.dll

> ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

C:\Python27\DLLs\cHeatmap-x64.dll

> ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

I can run heatmap 1.1 but that was before DLLs were added.

Comment: It looks like the DLLs were built with Visual Studio 2012.  Do you have it or the [VC++ 2012 redist](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679) installed?

Comment: Installed & restarted. No effect.

Comment: Try to manually load the 64-bit DLL with `ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary`. Ignore the 32-bit DLL since you're using 64-bit Python.

Comment: `import ctypes

heatmap = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("C:\Python27\DLLs\cHeatmap-x64.dll")
` Same error.

Comment: Did you install `vcredist_x64.exe`?

Comment: Yes vcredist_x64 2012 is installed.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know what's wrong.  I tested this in a 64-bit Python environment on a Windows 8 VM with the x64 VC++ redist installed.  The DLL in question successfully loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved. Blank DLL files were created by the build.bat because the environment variable vcinstalldir is blank if a full version of visual studio isn't installed. DLLs were blank, filesize 0KB

Loaded clean DLLs from github. Filesize 9 & 10kb.

Heatmap library imports & functions as designed.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this dll?
C:\Windows\System32\msvcr110.dll

Copying the dll from another computer fixed the problem for me, not sure how.

Comment: msvcr110.dll is part of the MicroSoft Visual C Runtime 11.0 (MSVCR110) environment. So instead of copying the DLL it is better to properly install the environment!

Comment: Yes msvcr110.dll exists and is in the C:\Windows\System32 directory.