# Continuing DLL problems with heatmap.py

Tags: python, dll, heatmap

I'm having the same problem as has been described [previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13458543/dll-load-failed-not-a-valid-win32-app-showing-for-both-x86-x64-dlls) regarding [heatmap.py](http://jjguy.com/heatmap/) and some dodgy dll files that spit out an "[Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application" error.

My problem is that I cannot find the relevant files - cHeatmap-x86.dll and cHeatmap-x64.dll - on github except for the ones from the original distribution (albeit uploaded only 8 months ago), which have the same issue. I assume the others have been taken down over the last 2 years. I am therefore unable to use the solution described in the previous question. Additionally, I have installed VC++ as described [here](https://github.com/jjguy/heatmap/issues/9) and re-run build.bat to no avail.

The only other solution I have read was to recompile the dlls from the .c source code, but that is well out of my knowledge base. Does anyone have functioning copies of these dll files that can go back on github, or is anyone able to make them with relatively little effort from the source code? Heatmap seems pretty powerful and unique, but currently it appears unusable without experience in multiple areas to fix the dlls. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: @cgohlke many thanks for the link. However, I am using Canopy and it refuses to install the wheel (as acknowledged in your link). I still require the DLLs as a more general fix to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After literally hours of fighting with this, I found a remarkably simple fix. I downloaded Visual Studio (there are perhaps less bulky programmes that can be used), opened the broken dll in VS, clicked "Save As", simply overwriting the existing file, and the error is gone.